# Aurelia JS - using a gist.run project with CLI (au run)?

Tags: aurelia

I want to try debugging this:

- https://gist.run/?id=57ed46429e4583eb4c3fb11814451a55

... however, I'm not sure how to run a `gist.run` type of project locally, with aurelia CLI.

This is what I do:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/aurtmp
$ cd /tmp/aurtmp
$ au new aurtmp --here
...
What platform are you targeting?           1. Web (Default)
What transpiler would you like to use?     1. Babel (Default)
What css processor would you like to use?  1. None (Default)
Would you like to configure unit testing?  2. No
What is your default code editor?          5. None of the Above
Would you like to create this project?     1. Yes (Default)
Would you like to install the project dependencies?  1. Yes (Default)
...
Installing project dependencies.
...
Congratulations! Your Project "aurtmp" Has Been Created!
...
Happy Coding!

$ git clone https://gist.github.com/anonymous/57ed46429e4583eb4c3fb11814451a55 tmpsrc
$ rsync -aP tmpsrc/ src/
$ rm -rf tmpsrc
```

Note at this point, there is both a `./index.html` (autogenerated) and `./src/index.html` (downloaded)

Ok, so if I run the file directly from the folder:

```
firefox ./src/index.html
```

... it actually seems to run, but I get in Error log:

```
syntax error                     app.js:1:1
...
syntax error       first-level-items.js:1:1
not well-formed   second-level-items.js:1:1
```

... which are not errors I get directly in gist.run (when using Chromium).

If I try the same with Chromium, however, I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///tmp/aurtmp/src/main.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
Error: XHR error loading file:///tmp/aurtmp/src/main.js(…)
```

... which I guess is self-explanatory.

If I try to build the project with `au run --watch` or `au build`, I get:

```
Tracing first-level-items...
{ uid: 8,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error: 
   { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/aurtmp/src/aurelia-kendoui-bridge/slider/slider.js']
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open', ...
```

So, is there a recommended and/or easy way to use/debug Aurelia projects from gist.run locally, with the au cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are running the latest version of the CLI (0.25.0) by running `au -v`. If you are not on the latest version of the CLI, then (in your case), you'll need to run `npm install -g aurelia-cli` to upgrade. Then create a new project in a new folder using `au new`.

Next, you need to install the `aurelia-kendoui-bridge` using the Aurelia CLI.

```
 au install aurelia-kendoui-bridge
```

It will run `npm install aurelia-kendoui-bridge` for you as well as modifying your `aurelia.json` file to include the kendo ui bridge.

Now that you've created a new project, you just need to copy all of the files from the gist, except for `index.html`, in to the `src` directory of your CLI project. You can overwrite the `main.js` and `app.[html|js]` files. Do not replace the `index.html` file with the one from the gist.

Next, run `au run` or `au run --watch` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Many thanks for that @AshleyGrant ; I am on version 0.23.0 of `au` CLI, so I guess it's time to update; also good to keep in mind about the `index.html`.

Comment: Hm, I did `npm install -g aurelia-cli`, it apparently passed, but then when running `au -v`, I get: `~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.6/lib/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/file-system.js:70 \n exports.join = function(...segments) { \n SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`.

Comment: What version of Node are you running? 0.26.1 has a regression that forces it to only work on an up to date version of Node (v6.9+). A fix is being discussed (we're considering if we want to support <6.9.x or not).

Comment: Hi @AshleyGrant - `node --version` for me reports `v4.2.6`; I've had to install this specific version for an unrelated project some time ago, and I'd need to keep it, in case I need to support the unrelated project.

Comment: @sdbbs you can use NVM (Node Version Manager) to quickly and easily switch between different versions of Node.